# Browser incompatibility problem

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

The code bellow works well with latest version of Chrome on Linux and Windows, latest version of Firefox in Linux and Windows, all IE versions on Windows except IE9.

Unfortunately, it does not work as expected with IE9 in Windows and latest version of Chrome and Firefox on MacOS

I did a couple of test and I found that the error happens when redirecting from the Facebook application's canvas page to another Facebook canvas application that uses an IFrame to show the first application. When redirection happens `$user` is null on the above mentioned browser on MacOS and IE on Windows but it is not null and working as expected for every browser mentioned in first paragraph.

Any suggestion?

```
<?php    
$user            =   null; //facebook user uid
try{
    include_once "src/facebook.php";
    include_once "src/fb_logger.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($o);
    echo '</pre>';
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$user       = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based 
// on whether the user is logged in.
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
// the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we dont know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos'
        )
);

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

            if(isset($_GET['iframe']) || isset($_GET['code']))) {
    }
    else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        if(window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('iframe') != -1 || window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('oauth') != -1 || window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('code') != -1) {
        }
        else
                            //opening new application with iframe to show the previous one
            window.open('link to the iframe pointing to the this application', '_parent', '');
        </script>";
        exit;
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //you should use error_log($e); instead of printing the info on browser
    //d($e);  // d is a debug function defined at the end of this file
    $user = null;
  }
}

if (!$user) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe related to `'cookie' => true,` on a first glance. Are the cookies properly set in the browser you're having problems with? What do the browsers report which cookies they have?

Comment: I do not have access to Chrome or Firefox on a Mac right now but I tested the application again with IE9 on Windows. Before testing I went to `Internet Options` - `Privacy` - and I set the option there to `Accept all cookies`. And its working. Can you suggest any workaround?

Comment: I didn't mean to check the options, but was interested in the actual raw cookie headers and the interpretation of those in the datastructures of the browser. No idea about IE9 handles them and where to reach them. My support for IE has ended with IE 6 which does the job quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution

I added:

```
//required for IE in iframe FB environments if sessions are to work.
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

in my code and it's now working.

Comment: I always forget about this.  Damn P3P headers.  Yay for stack overflow.

Comment: Btw, I've got it working with a reduced set that I stole from here: http://tempe.st/2010/11/cookies-in-iframes-how-bashing-my-head-on-the-table-made-them-work-in-internet-explorer/. Just  "NOI DSP LAW NID"